# how to check if a class has its meta class definition in mach-o file

Tags: mach-o, mach

So I am learning mach-o file.

Now I was able to tell how to map a pointer to a class struct, but I found that, if I use otool, sometimes it will print out something has meta class:

```
00000001000990d8 0x1000b75c8
           isa 0x1000b75f0
    superclass 0x0
         cache 0x0
        vtable 0x0
          data 0x1000a5a00 (struct class_ro_t *)
                    flags 0x184 RO_HAS_CXX_STRUCTORS
            instanceStart 8
             instanceSize 152
                 reserved 0x0
               ivarLayout 0x10007bb99
                layout map: 0x1f 0x02 
                     name 0x10007bb93 AASDK
```

and after this class_ro_t *, there is one section right after it:

```
Meta Class
           isa 0x0
    superclass 0x0
         cache 0x0
        vtable 0x0
          data 0x1000a5730 (struct class_ro_t *)
                    flags 0x185 RO_META RO_HAS_CXX_STRUCTORS
            instanceStart 40
             instanceSize 40
                 reserved 0x0
               ivarLayout 0x0
                     name 0x10007bb93 AASDK
              baseMethods 0x1000a5698 (struct method_list_t *)
```

And this seems like meta class has the methods declared as class methods (marked with `+` in ObjC code)

The memory layout looks like:

```
1000B75C8: F0 75 0B 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
1000B75D8: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
1000B75E8: 00 5A 0A 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
1000B75F8: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
1000B7608: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  30 57 0A 00 01 00 00 00 
1000B7618: 40 76 0B 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

We can obviously see that `30 57 0A 00 01 00 00 00` is the meta class data pointer.

I wonder, how to tell if the class has meta class info?

I checked the otool source code, but I can't read it, it has lots of calculations and offsets. Can someone help explain how to check it?